# ADO.NET/WCF Data Service - POST to Stored Procedure

Tags: wcf, stored-procedures, ado.net-entity-data-model, wcf-data-services

Is it possible to trigger a function import/service operation with a POST as you might POST data to an EntitySet?

At the end of the day, I would like to post a bunch of arguments to a stored procedure. POST because some of the paramaters are large XML NText strings.

Options thus far:
1. Decorate a custom method with WebInvoke, post data into a stream, decypher and manually run function (which in turn execs stored proc)
2. Create an Entity representing the arguments to the procedure and map the entity onto the procedure for the insert statement. Post XML representing the entity to the endpoint. (entity yields Field  is not mapped compile time errors)

Any thoughts/links on the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Hi @Kyle, did you ever solve this one?